# Lutris/wine creating multiple windows installs

Tags: wine, games, lutris

6 months ago I tried the ubuntu system for the first time and it ended up becoming my main operating system. The main point for me was the fact that 2 games that I really wanted to play didn't run correctly on windows and when I installed it on ubuntu not only the problems were corrected but I also had fps gain. So i decided to install other games to see the results. The first 2 I had used steam's proton which worked perfectly, but there were also some in my epic games so I had to use lutris and wine

I installed them and it was perfect. In the 3rd month of using ubuntu, I formatted the system to clean it of all the rubbish that I had put on it because I knew how to mess with the system a little bit and now I'm having problems with lutirs/wine.

Basically every time I use lutris to install something through wine, lutris creates a brand new copy of wine which ends up consuming a lot of hd space. Every new game creates a new system and if I install it directly through epic games in wine, the dependencies are not installed correctly and the games end up not running.

I want to know if there is a way to make lutris install everything from wine on the same system and in the same folder

i use Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

[folder that has the system on which lutris wanted to install batman arkham city](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1Sao.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create a installer, with the name like "Windows 10" and install every game that you want inside it. But, this will break because windows has all native libs, and wine you need to configure to get the installation to fit close of software you want install. This is the pattern applied to Lutris games, every game has its own configuration that match its requirements.